# docker: failed to compute cache key: "/requirements.txt" not found: not found

Tags: dockerfile, docker-build

I tried to build a docker image with the following command:

`docker build -< Dockerfile`

I did it in the main directory of the app. I found this command somewhere in a documentation "how to build a docker image". However the build failed with failure:

`failed to compute cache key: "/requirements.txt" not found: not found`

My test-app structure looks like:

```
.
+-- src
|   +-- static
|   +-- templates
|   +-- app.py
+-- Dockerfile
+-- requirements.txt
```

I'm not a docker expert and there are several instructions out there. It's somehow frustrating. Other stack overflow questions did not solve my issue.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4):

After some investigation and try out i found the following solution:

The command `docker build -> Dockerfile` was somehow wrong. Don't know if it is outdated or incomplete.

However i used the following command and it worked:

`docker build --tag docker_example .`

Very important is the dot at the and. Without this it will not work. It tells Docker which Dockerfile to use.

If you have a "custom" Dockerfile name like "something.Dockerfile" you have to add the -f option followed by the name of your Dockerfile to build the right one.

Example:

`docker build --tag docker_example -f something.Dockerfile .`

Comment: `docker build - <Dockerfile` sends _only_ the Dockerfile to the Docker daemon but not any of the rest of the build context, so your `COPY` commands will fail.

Comment: thanks David for the explanation. Do you now, what the use case is for this command? Why should I "send" the Dockerfile to the daemon, but not build the image?

Comment: I'm a little hard-pressed to think of a use case for it.  It's also possible to [send a tar file on stdin](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/#build-with--) which I can imagine some technical uses for, particularly before there were multi-stage builds.